# Confusion on push_back interaction with pair<float,int>

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I have no error message instead I only have unexpected behavior.

```cpp
double get_optimal_value(int capacity, vector<int> weights, vector<int> values) {
  int n = weights.size();
  vector<pair<double, int>> valuePerWeight(n);
  pair<double,int> x;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
    double v = values[i]/weights[i]; 
    x = make_pair(values[i]/weights[i], weights[i]);
    valuePerWeight.push_back(x);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < n && capacity > 0; i++){
    int amount = min(capacity, valuePerWeight[i].second);
    value += valuePerWeight[i].first * amount;
    capacity -= amount;
  }

  double value = 0.0;
  return value;
}
```

I am creating a vector with values of type `pair<double,int>`. I create the pair using `make_pair(some_double, some_int)`, then I call `push_back` with the pair.

Later in the function I index into the vector and do stuff using the pairs.
However an issue arises, when I index into my `valuePerWeight` vector and retrieve the attributes of the different pairs. They all end up being zero regardless of index and regardless of `.first` or `.second`.

Through printing a bunch of variables I have asserted the created pair is not {0,0} but as soon as I `push_back` into the vector and index the pair and look at it's `.first` and `.second` attributes both are equal to 0.

I can't seem to understand why this is, originally I was using `push_back` seen as below

```cpp
valuePerWeight.push_back(make_pair(values[i]/weights[i], weights[i]));
```

instead of creating into a temporary variable `x` . However the same issue still stands.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
If there is any further clarification that I can give please ask me.

If you'd like to see for some values below is a snippet which can be compiled

I use input

```
3 50 
60 20
100 50
120 30
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

double get_optimal_value(int capacity, vector<int> weights, vector<int> values) {
  double value = 0.0;
  int n = weights.size();
  vector<pair<double, int>> valuePerWeight(n);
  pair<double,int> x;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

    double v = values[i]/weights[i];
    cout << v << ' '<< weights[i] << '\n';
    x = make_pair(values[i]/weights[i], weights[i]);
    cout << x.first << ' ' << x.second << '\n';

    valuePerWeight.push_back(x);
    cout << valuePerWeight[i].first << ' ' << valuePerWeight[i].second << '\n';
  }


  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << valuePerWeight[i].first;
    cout << valuePerWeight[i].second;

    cout << '\n';
  }

  sort(valuePerWeight.begin(), valuePerWeight.end());

  for(int i = 0; i < n && capacity > 0; i++){
    int amount = min(capacity, valuePerWeight[i].second);
    value += valuePerWeight[i].first * amount;
    capacity -= amount;
  }



  // for(auto vp: valuePerWeight){
  //   cout << vp.first << vp.second;
  //   cout << '\n';
  // }

  return value;
}

int main() {
  int n;
  int capacity;
  std::cin >> n >> capacity;
  vector<int> values(n);
  vector<int> weights(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cin >> values[i] >> weights[i];
  }

  double optimal_value = get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values);

  std::cout.precision(10);
  std::cout << optimal_value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but probably a bug too: `values[i]/weights[i]` is an integer division. This doesn't change just because the result is stored as double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion here is due to the behavior of the constructor you use

```
vector<pair<double, int>> valuePerWeight(n);
```

This actually fills the vector with `n` default constructed pairs, which as you may surmise, are (0, 0). When you `push_back`, you push to the end of these, so you a totally get `2n` pairs.

`.reserve` does something close to what you expected, not actually filling the vector, but is likely not needed for something not bottle-necking on vector resizing.

Short story, omit the `(n)` to just construct an empty vector.

Three more suggestions: accept the vectors as `const&` to save a copy, and look at `emplace_back` instead of making a pair yourself and pushing it. That's what it's meant for.  Also, note the comment by [churill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63555303/confusion-on-push-back-interaction-with-pairfloat-int/63555405#comment112384674_63555303) - dividing two integers will result in integer division regardless of where you are assigning the result. Static cast one of them to a float or double (or multiply by 1.0 at the start) to ensure floating point division.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is very informative.

When you say accept as ```const&``` are you referring to the functions parameters.

```emplace_back``` is exactly what I need, I would have never thought to look for something like this, and would have only found it through someone helpful like yourself or chance, should I try to dive into documentation to find helpful things like this or should just code and look at code to familiarize myself with the tools available.

Comment: @ConfusionIsConstant You are quite welcome. Yes, regarding the `const&`. A common semantic when passing objects in C++, especially if they can be large and to avoid problems with non-copyable objects, is to take function arguments as `const type& argument`, where type is a `std::vector<int>` for example. This avoids the copy and makes it clear you intended to take something you do not want to change.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion on correcting my double bug.